# Tomcat - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

A method in my app works fine with local / JUnit however when deployed to Tomcat version 7-latest (or even version 9 latest) then things start to break:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        ... 95 more
```

I've already added these dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
  </dependency>
```

What could be the actual solution for this?

Comment: How do you package and deploy to tomcat?

Comment: check the lib folder in the deployed app, eclipse maven plugin has a bug where it sometimes doesn't add dependencies to the lib folder

Comment: @nullpointer a Shaded Jar is loaded by Tomcat via custom class loader

Comment: @xybrek Any chances you can check the shaded jar for its content. Could possibly be a miss at that phase.

Comment: @nullpointer I checked the jar using Winrar and can see the AnnotationReader.class on the folder path

Comment: which java version are you running?